# Keypad Sent or Done button not visible in WildFire a3333

Tags: android, keyboard, android-keypad

I use **android:imeOptions="actionSend"** or **android:imeOptions="actionDone"** in xml for Edittext. Send or Done key is visible for all the simulator QVGA,HVGA,WVGA.... but while installing the application in my HTC WildFire a3333 return key is visible no action is happening in this key

**Note:** I can not use any third party keypad in my android phone.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i find answer i use android:imeOptions="actionDone" i overwritten the done action in java code it will work for all the device.